# Preloaded SQLite local DB in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sqlite

**Problem**

I wanna use [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) framework on my project to access my local preloaded (read-only) database file (db.sqlite3) which located in my current project directory. I created my db connection as `let db = try? Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")` First question is when I keep my db in my project directory can I involve connection path as `Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")` or `Connection("db.sqlite3")`? (What's the meaning of path/to of course, I'm wondering) Anyway, my main question is how can I query my local db? What's wrong?

Here is my code but it doesn't work. This code mostly similar to SQLite.swift's github [documantion page](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift#usage) but it doesn't work in Swift 2.2

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let db = try? Connection("path/to/db.sqlite3")

    let users = Table("users")

    for user in try! db!.prepare(users) {
        print("id: \(user[id]), name: \(user[name]), email: \(user[email])")
        // id: 1, name: Optional("Alice"), email: alice@mac.com
    }

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I have already copied my db files to Copy Bundle Resources (Build Phrase)

**My working directory**

[image]

**Error**
[image]

Note: I tried db connection as "path/to/db.sqlite3" and "db.sqlite3". So, this is not the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated for Swift 3+**

I read the documantation carefully again and found the answer like this:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "db", ofType: "sqlite3")!

    let db = try? Connection(path, readonly: true)

    for row in try! db!.prepare("SELECT id, email FROM users") {
        print("\(row[0]!), \(row[1]!)")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Converted in **Swift 3.0**

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SMP", ofType: "sqlite")!
let db = try? Connection(path)
```

// **Insert** Rows ======

```
let stmt = try! db!.prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_workout (name) VALUES (?)")
for name in ["Workout1", "Workout2"] {
       try! stmt.run(name)
}
```

// **Fetch** Rows ======

```
for row in try! db!.prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_workout") {
    print("id: \(String(describing: row[0])), email: \(String(describing: row[1]))")
}
```